# Regex to find content in html tags

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to parse a html file and extract the NeedThis* strings with C#/.net, sample code is:

```
<tr class="class">
    <td style="width: 120px">
        <a href="NeedThis1">NeedThis2</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 120px">
        <a href="NeedThis3">
            NeedThis4</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 30%">
        NeedThis5
    </td>
    <td>
        NeedThis6
    </td>
    <td style="width: 120px">
        NeedThis7
    </td>
</tr>
```

I know a html parser should be better here, but all I need is to extract these texts, this is just for a temp helper tool...

anyone can help me with this?

thanks!

Comment: I would like to cite the first answer of this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I already seen that, I just don't want to use IndexOf... as I said, this is for a temp helper tool, not a final product... I need to extract these strings from about 50k files, which is stored in my local HDD and insert in a database, once done, ctrl + delete the tool =)

Comment: @Soravux: We think alike -- I was about to do the same, then I saw your comment :-)

Comment: @Hans W I am not sure how to use RegEx in C#, but the expression is pretty simple `(NeedThis\\*)`  You can generate your own RegEx expressions and test them here:  http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: thanks! but needthis can be any arbitrary string, maybe I should have explained it better

Comment: It'll be faster to add the HTMLAgilityPack and grab the strings through DOM traversal than it would be to write and verify the regexes that may or may not work on all 50K files.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that you html is valid you could use Linq to Xml else you are better of using a parser  like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter whether you're doing this for a one-off or for a "finished project". Your task isn't text extraction and it's not something that a regex can do effectively. The data you're looking for depends on the structure of the HTML. Your task is parsing HTML. When your task is parsing HTML, use an HTML parser. It's not difficult. In fact it's a lot *easier* than writing the pile of regexes you would need otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have answered your own question. ***[You should use a parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)***. But if you don't you can use the RE `NeedThis.*`

Of course, if you want any context with those strings, you should just use a parser.

Comment: In that case, **USER A PARSER**

Comment: @Hans W Glad to see you proving that programmers are still as naturally resistant to good ideas as ever.

Answer (score 0):

Hans, as you can see by the other answers using a RegEx is probably not the best way to do what you want to do, but since I need to practice my RegEx anyways I went ahead and made one just in case you wanted to experiment.  This will only catch `NeedThis2`, but it should give you an idea of how you would make your own RegEx when it is an appropriate solution.

```
<a href="NeedThis1">NeedThis2</a>
```

RegEx to catch `NeedThis2`:

```
(?:<a[^<a]+?>)(\S)*(?:<[^<]+?a>)
```

Pretty nasty huh? :)